# git status and pass to rsync for content compare

Tags: git, bash, rsync

*nix noob here,

I need to do the following on centos/rhel:
run git status, take the output of the files listed there and pass them to rsync -avcn soure-dir/target-dir/

I understand how to do both, but not how to format or pass the files returned from git to rsync.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`git status` by itself doesn't just list files, it contains a long human-readable status message.  Perhaps you are looking for something like

```
git status --porcelain | sed -n 's/^?? //p'
```

to get just a list of uncommitted files?

But in general, if you can find a way to produce a list of just the files you want, you can do

```
rsync -avcn soure-dir/target-dir/ $(command-to-list-files)
```

or

```
command-to-list-files |
xargs rsync -avcn soure-dir/target-dir/
```

The latter is more robust when there are file names containing whitespace or other special characters (though you will need to play with `xargs` options to make proper use of this feature) and when there are more files than will fit on a single command line (you get "Command line too long").

Comment: Perfect.  This info will get me exactly on the right path.  Thanks!

Comment: @tek0011 Did you create a `$(command-to-list-files)`? I am interested in creating a similar solution and that code would save me some time. Thanks.